# I don't have any keymap for "view selected"

Tags: shortcut

I am following a tutorial and they are teaching how to configure the hotkey for "view selected" but when I try to find the actual configuration I don't see any hotkey already created:

[image]

I just installed the program, I also tried to "Load factory preferences" but still not any hotkey found for this functionality

Is it normal that I don't have these hotkeys? I know I can add this hotkey manually but I am worried my configuration has a bigger mess

Comment: maybe you're talking about Show Active (Numpad ".")?

Comment: The option seems to be renamed from 2.90 probably which didn't really add any clarity. Anyway you can find the operator in the viewport header menu > View > Frame Selected. If it has any hotkey, that will be shown there (or in the Search menu as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Preferences key map screen shot]

I believe that "View Selected" in the keymap has been renamed to "Frame Selected."